# Is it acceptable to use ‘middle-aged’ to describe an animal such as a cow?

Tags: synonyms

Does the following sentence sound correct in English:

“She is a cow: neither is she advanced in years nor is she a heifer, but she is middle-aged in between them.

Is there a technical term for animals in their “middle-ages”? Would you say the word middle-aged word is suitable for describing ages of animals?

Comment: What is full age for a cow? Is it a cow in some sort of natural circumstance, or one being raised as food?

Comment: Most people don't ever discuss the ages of animals, except their pets, so there aren't common terms. There might be words in the farming industry, you'd have to ask in one of their forums (but not farmersonly.com).

Comment: We do talk about baby animals and old animals, so I don't see why we couldn't use middle aged as well.

Comment: It'll be hard to guess, as to the acceptability to the cow...

Comment: It is assumed that the cow is in a natural circumstance  @JackO'Flaherty

Comment: If you _do_ use it, the words _in between them_ are not needed. We all know what _middle-aged_ means.

Comment: @mueenkhurshid Maybe just an adult or full-grown cow. That excludes calves, and doesn't suggest old.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help